# Discord bot disconnects before finishing music

Tags: discord.py

I'm using DiscordUtils for this exact bot. The music plays somewhere around halfway (every song) and stops with the bot displaying information that there is no song playing. Here is my code (no errors show up).

I cannot seem to find any information regarding this that contains information regarding DiscordUtils. I only get results for YouTube-DL and sadly it works differently. Is there any exact solution to this problem, is this an FFMPEG error?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord import Client, Intents, Embed
from discord.ext.commands.core import command
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option
import DiscordUtils
import ffmpeg


music = DiscordUtils.Music()
activity = discord.Game(name="around. Use /help")
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', activity=activity)
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    voicetrue = ctx.author.voice
    if voicetrue is None:
        return await ctx.send('You are not currently in a voice channel. :exclamation:')
    await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
    await ctx.send('Joined the voice chat you are in. :white_check_mark:')

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voicetrue = ctx.author.voice
    mevoicetrue = ctx.guild.me.voice
    if voicetrue is None:
        return await ctx.send('You are not currently in the same voice channel as I am.')
    if mevoicetrue is None:
        return await ctx.send('Im not currently in any voice channel!')
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    await ctx.send('I have disconnected from the voice channel.')

@client.command()
async def play(ctx, *, url):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    if not player:
        player = music.create_player(ctx, ffmpeg_error_bettercix=True)
    if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
        await player.queue(url, search=True)
        song = await player.play()
        await ctx.send(f'Playing **{song.name}** :notes:')
    else:
        song = await player.queue(url, search=True)
        await ctx.send(f'Ive added **{song.name}** to the queue!')

@client.command()
async def queue(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    await ctx.send(f"The music queue currently is: **{', '.join([song.name for song in player.current_queue()])}**")

@client.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.pause()
    await ctx.send(f'Paused **{song.name}** :pause_button:')

@client.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.resume()
    await ctx.send(f'Resumed **{song.name}** :arrow_forward:')

@client.command()
async def loop(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.toggle_song_loop()
    if song.is_looping:
        return await ctx.send(f'{song.name} will now start looping. :repeat:')
    else:
        return await ctx.send(f'{song.name} will no longer loop. :no_entry:')

@client.command()
async def nowplaying(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = player.now_playing()
    if song.name is None:
        await ctx.send(song.name + ' is currently playing.')

@client.command()
async def remove(ctx, index):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.remove_from_queue
    await ctx.send(f'Removed {song.name} from the song queue!')
    

@slash.slash(
    name="hello",
    description="Hello there!",
    guild_ids=[822512275331219517, 708384142978711582, 747869167889285180]
)
async def _hello(ctx:SlashContext):
    await ctx.send("Hi! test command")

@slash.slash(
    name="help",
    description="Recieve help using Anix",
    guild_ids=[822512275331219517, 708384142978711582, 747869167889285180]
)
async def _help(ctx:SlashContext):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Commands to get you going", description="", color=0xff131a)
    embed.set_author(name="Anix Help")
    embed.add_field(name="?play", value="use this command whilst in a voice channel to start music", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="?join", value="make Anix join your voice channel", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="?leave", value="make Anix leave your voice channel", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="?queue", value="check the music queue", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="?pause", value="pauses the current song that's playing", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="?resume", value="resumes a paused song", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="?loop", value="loops the current song (type again to stop loop)", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="?nowplaying", value="check the song that's currently playing", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="?remove", value="removes the currently playing song from the queue", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embeds=[embed])

client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing `import ffmpeg` the disconnecting problem no longer occurs. All of the commands work with no problems whatsoever.